# Run exe using Java as administrator

Tags: java, windows, exe, runtime.exec, administrator

How to run exe file as administrator if you know admin login and password?

I have tried with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState\"");
```

but it asks for password, I want to write admin login and password in Java code.

Comment: As general advice.  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: As a suggestion, don't directly use Runtime#exec() method to invoke a process. It might cause both the processes (JVM and the invoked process) to hang if you are not consuming the streams created by the invoked process. You can use apache commons exec library which has utility method to consume the streams associated with the process.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the help of `runas` command.

```
NOTE:  Enter user's password only when prompted.
NOTE:  /profile is not compatible with /netonly.
NOTE:  /savecred is not compatible with /smartcard.
```

Comment: Thanks! but don't java have another alternatives other than "runas" to do this work?

Comment: Its better to handle it using a batch script, if you want to store the password. But I would prefer user to enter the password since we don't know if the password has been changed.